# Bicep - How to initialize app files of PowerShell Azure Function (e.g. requirements.psd1)?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-bicep

We are using [Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview) to create an Azure Function App running a PowerShell function. This works well, except one detail.

Part of the function app definition are app files that we need to initialize upon creation, specifically *requirements.psd1*, where required modules are listed:

[image]

Can this be done in a Bicep file? If yes: how? If not: what is the recommended way of doing it?

(We are using Azure CLI with Bicep (`az bicep`), so a solution in that context would be nice.)

Comment: Have you gone through this [Managed Dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#manageddependency) which will initialize the `requirements.psd1` automatically.

Comment: It is set, yes. But I need to add my specific dependencies to requirements.psd1, in this case "PnP.PowerShell" and "Az.Accounts".

Comment: Looking for exactly the same - did you find a good solutions for it @HeinrichUlbricht

Comment: @keram I use a workaround, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm for now resorting to deploying the requirements.psd1 file after the Bicep deployment. (Note: the Bicep deployment resets the file content on every deployment.)

Here's the Azure CLI command:

```
az webapp deploy --resource-group rg-contoso-test-westeurope --name func-contoso-test-westeurope --src-path "../../Azure/Functions/ContosoFunc/requirements.psd1" --clean false --target-path "/home/site/wwwroot/requirements.psd1" --type static
```

Answer (score 0):

Late but I've actually found an solution for this:

```
resource function 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: azureFunctionApp
  name: 'BackupTable'
  properties: {
    ...
    files: {
      'run.ps1' : loadTextContent('../FunctionApp/DailyBackup/run.ps1')
      '../requirements.psd1' : loadTextContent('../FunctionApp/requirements.psd1')
    }
  }
}
```

Add the 'requirements.psd1' in the files of your function and it will work! For me at least.. i hope for others too.